# Related to pass push notication + passbook + ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios6, passbook

do we need device to test the push notification. can we implement pass with out using a push notiification, i mean if we wants to update a pass from the server, do we really require a device

Answer (score 1):

The iOS simulator does not support web services, so if you want to test push deliveries, registration or pass updates you will need to test with an iOS7 device.